# Why this transaction is valid?

Tags: transaction-verification, input-script

The before transaction is @ https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/tx/da58f6688b0727a7f1bf3eec899099bde1f18b9c7099f9d2c79556db238e623d

Its output script is "OP_HASH160 da1745e9b549bd0bfa1a569971c77eba30cd5a4b OP_EQUAL".

The current transaction is @
https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/tx/839b903b9f79c3372792ceb95917047c46d1b919ed1f6471f5a19d7c865ab32c?txinIdx=0

Its input script is "51".

I verified the transaction manually but it failed.
Why the transaction was accepted and confirmed?

The evolved stack is as below. What's wrong?
628850cb844fe63c308c62afc8bc5351f1952a7f = RIPEMD160(SHA256(1))
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The transaction is valid. [This](https://gist.github.com/RaghavSood/e9e39cb5c258da67273c67c05b5ffdc1) golang code gives the correct result.

You need to HASH160 `51`, not `1`.

Additionally, make sure you run the hash on `0x51`, not `"51"` or `int(51)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Raghav! I cannot access the golang code on github. Could  you please update the url link? Thanks again.

Comment: @JDoe That's odd. Seems to work for me. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/jfFWpBKg) the same code on pastebin